# Obtaining the PMF of the ratio of two discrete random variables.

Tags: probability-theory

I have the pmf of "a" discrete random variable and also of another discrete random variable "b". Now, I want to obtain the resulting pmf of "a/b". How to do this? I want the PMF and not the PDF.

Comment: can they both only take on finitely many values? Because then you can simply find the individual probabilities of all possible ratios

Comment: If we know the distributions of the two rv, and that  the rv are independent, look at the possible values, compute the relevant probabilities.  If they are not independent, we will probably need the joint distribution function. For details one would need the actual problem.

Comment: They can take values at certain particular values, as is the property of a pmf. "a" and "b" are independent among themselves.

Comment: In probability books I have seen, the PMF and PDF of a discrete random variable are the same thing. Please give the definitions you are using. Also, it is obvious that there need to be some restrictions on the two random variables. To begin the one in the denominator cannot take 0 values. Finally, you need to give the source of the problem and some indication as to what you have tried and why you are asking for assistance.

Comment: The approach for a PDF is well known, but I am not sure whether it can be applied for PMFs also. And as far as I know, PDFs are for continuous random variables and PMFs are for the discrete ones.